How to re-share shared folder for Windows 10 devices?
I'm giving up and asking for your help.
I have a domain network with some computers and I need to re-share a shared folder from one domain PC to another domain PC or Laptop. But origin of that shared folder is from a non-domain PC.
Here is the scheme of network connection:

My situation
So the PC1 has two ethernet adapters: ETH1 and ETH2. The ETH1 is connected to the domain network and the ETH2 is connected directly to the PC2 (non-domain PC).
So that PC2 has network connection only with the PC1. The PC2 is a small factory PC (SFF) built-in into the machine.
In the PC2 I created a shared folder for Everyone - full control, \PC2\images, see an image below:

Shared folder is visible into PC1 so I can copy files from PC2 to PC1:

And now comes the funniest part - I need to create an access to this PC2's shared folder for other users into the domain network.
I found only way how to re-shared shared folder and it's via mklink command executed in the PC1:
C:\>mk1ink /d C:\temp\SharedPC2 \\192.168.61.100\images


Thanks to the mklink a I can create something like shortcut/folder which is connected with the \PC2\images\ and it is possible to share it from PC1 to the other domain users.

Now let's move from the PC1 to another domain device like Laptop-LAP1. From that LAP1 I can see the re-shared folder.
But I can't open this re-shared folder and after few seconds an error message will appear:

For a test purpose I've created a shared folder "SharedPC1-test" on the PC1 with same permissions as for PC2's folder and it worked. So SMB or firewall issue should be excluded:

Devices configuration
PC1 ETH1 configuration (domain network)`
IPv4 10.100.150.200
Sub 255.255.255.0
GW 10.100.160.254
DHCP 10.100.140.10
DNS 10.100.140.1
DNS 10.100.140.2
Firewall - exception for file transfer


PC1 ETH2 configuration (local network with PC2)
IPv4 192.168.60.200
Sub 255.255.255.0
Firewall - exception for file transfer

.
PC2 ETH configuration (non domain PC)
IPv4 192.168.60.100
Sub 255.255.255.0
Firewall - disabled

.
PC1, PC2, LAP1 configuration
OS Windows 10
SMB, File/pritner share - enbaled

Possible solutions
I've tried some solutions but without success, like:

use "route add" commands with many variations for PC1 or LAP1

For example, PC1> route add 10.100.150.200 mask 255.255.252.0 192.168.60.100 IF 4

disable firewall on every device
create same local admin account and add record to the Windows "Credential Manager"

Workaround
I know how to workaround this issue. But I'm looking for something smart, easy and how to deal with it directly in Windows with its resources.
1st Workaround: use robocopy or sync software to sync folders between PC2 and PC1 and then share synced folder from PC1.
2nd Workaround: attach cable and connect PC2 directly to the domain network with second network adapter.So PC2 will be available into the domain network.
